# UIImage imagewithData returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm storing images taken on the iPhone camera and saving them onto a server as a string like this:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

And after retrieving them from the server I am trying to convert them into an image like this:

```
NSData *data = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    if (image)
    {
        [self.bagImagesArray addObject:image];
    }
```

"image" always returns nil... logging out the data it seems to be absolutely fine

It must be either the way I'm converting the initial image OR the way I'm converting the data into an image but I have no idea where to start and google isn't really helping much

Any help would be great

*** UPDATE ***

Tried this too

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:dataStr options:0];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Logging out "image" shows that it thinks it is a UIButton... wat?

**UPDATE**

dataStr looks like this

```
<ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 00060000 87690004 00000001 00000026 00000000 0003a001 00030000 00010001 0000a002 00040000 00010000 0cc0a003 00040000 00010000 09900000 0000ffed 00385068 6f746f73 686f7020...51494005 2d250680 168a4a5a 061494b4 50014669 28a0028a 05068016 8a4a5eb4 001a4a0d 2d001451 45001451 45001452 5283400d a2968a00 ffd9>
```

Obviously a lot longer but you get the picture

Comment: did you missed base64 decoding ?

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage.image);

Comment: @sage444 - Just tried it... see my edit

Comment: ok, can you somehow show the data, because it's like telepathy without it

Comment: @sage444 - pasted a small chunk of the data in the latest edit

Answer (score 0):

While saving:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

While Reading:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: The server call isn't an issue.. I only pasted the line that processes the data, the api call is handled elsewhere in my code. The database just stores a JSON string which is why I'm having to store the NSData as a string in the first place... the API returning NSData is not a thing

Comment: Got you! I've updated my post. Could you please try with that. @RyanOfCourse

Comment: Image still returns as nil :(

Comment: I was wondering if you could find a solution for this? If so, please enlighten :) @RyanOfCourse

Comment: Still haven't found a solution, I had other stuff that was higher priority at the moment as this whole thing is because of a temporary APi I'm using until the back-end guy gives me the real api... it won't be an issue in the future but it'd be helpful to get it fixed for prototyping

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:dataStr options:0];
```

with

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:dataStr options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```

Comment: Just tried this, the image now returns as nil instead of a UIButton.. so still not a working solution unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I wondered but your data looks like jpeg image at least first bytes contains `JFIF` signature
[check here](http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=FFD8FFE0&mode=SIG)

is there any chance that image corrupted in network ?

also can you to try write data to file and open on mac, maybe something becomes more clear then